# Converting objects into json format - iOS

Tags: ios, json

Hi I am trying to convert my local data into json format on iOS. 
Format is as follows,

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "question_id": 2,
            "answer": "4",
            "question_instance_id": 146
        },
        {
            "question_id": 2,
            "answer": "4",
            "question_instance_id": 147
        },
        {
            "question_id": 2,
            "answer": "4",
            "question_instance_id": 148
        },
        {
            "question_id": 3,
            "answer": "Hdhd",
            "question_instance_id": 149
        }
    ],
    "last_name": "Jd",
    "first_name": "Js",
    "survey_id": 41
}
```

I went through various blogs where they explained about json encoding. But I am still not able to figure out how to handle nested dictionaries to convert data into json form as given in this example.

I appreciate for any help.

Comment: Parse it with a JSON parser (of which there are a half-dozen for iOS), the navigate the resulting dictionary containing an array containing dictionaries with good the old array/dictionary access methods.  If all else fails look at any of the easily 1000 prior questions on this topic and see how they were answered.

Comment: Though your question could be interpreted as asking how to go the other direction, in which case the answer is to put your data into the appropriate dictionaries and arrays and run them through a JSON serializer.  See 500 prior questions.

Comment: If you read my question properly, i am not trying to parse it but rather trying to convert into above mentioned format. Complication i am facing is that it is consist of nested dictionaries and that is what confuses me. "appropriate dictionaries and arrays" even i could tell that nyways

Comment: If you NSLog your outermost dictionary and the log looks like the above, only there are `()` characters in the NSLog where there are `[]` above, then you have the right structure.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was i was not clear with dictioneries and arrays structure inside json data. Now that is clear, i am able to put it into json format.

Comment: Yes, JSON is blazingly simple once you understand the basics.  I still don't get why so many people have so much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with iOS arrays and dictionaries, then you can visualize how they relate to JSON. JSON is just an encoding of arrays and dictionaries, so if you match up your data into structures that relate to what you have, the JSON encoding will be the same.

If you paste your above JSON into a JSON parser like this one:

[JSON PARSER PAGE](http://json.parser.online.fr)

You can see the underlying structure:

a Dictionary with 4 key/value pairs, with keys: "Answers", "last_name", "first_name", and "survey_id".  All the values for the keys are primitives, strings or numbers, except for the first "answers", whose value is a array of sub-dictionaries, all with keys: "question_id", "answer" and "question_instance_id"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `NSJSONSerialization` for this and what you require will be done automatically. Please also take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/) link. 
Thanks

---

Here's a 30 second summary of the linked wonderlich tutorial, it may help someone. Cheers.

Everything you ever need to know about json, and it doesn't even scroll on SO :)

```
#define exampleURL [NSURL URLWithString:\
 @"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]
-(void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; [self _jsonGet]; }

-(void)_jsonGet
    {
    NSLog(@"I'm getting some JSON data from the net.");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
        NSData* dataFromNet = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:exampleURL];
        [self _jsonParse:dataFromNet];
        });
    }

-(void)_jsonParse:(NSData *)jdat
    {
    NSLog(@"I did seem to get the data .. now parsing" );
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* jdic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jdat
        options:kNilOptions
        error:&error];
    // do this NSLog(@"%@", jdic); to see the fields available

    NSArray* latestLoans = [jdic objectForKey:@"loans"];
    NSLog(@"loans.count: %d \n\n\n", latestLoans.count);
    NSDictionary *oneLoan = latestLoans[3];
    NSLog(@"loans[3]: %@ \n\n\n\n", oneLoan);

    NSLog(@"...name: %@ \n\n\n\n", [oneLoan objectForKey:@"name"] ); 
    NSLog(@"...sector: %@ \n\n\n\n", [oneLoan objectForKey:@"sector"] ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
  NSDictionary *entireJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

The logic inside your `NSDictionary` is the same as your JSON. For your answers, you could something like this:

```
NSArray *answersArray = entireJSon[@"answers"];
```

Quick note, make sure your json is valid (in this case is...)